# How to transfer files one-way every x minutes from remote machine?

Tags: networking, raspberrypi

Here's my setup:

- Dell Dimension w/ Ubuntu Server 12.10 running 24/7 at a remote location outside my internal network

  - 1TB ext HD attached to server, actively downloading movies/tv
- Raspberry Pi w/ OpenELEC & XBMC running locally

  - 4TB HD attached to Pi, *hopefully receiving content from server*

I'd like to transfer video files from the server over to my Pi's external HD every x mins/hours, once they've finished downloading. I do not need to delete them from the remote location automatically, but in the event I clean them up, I do not want a two-way sync.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a script, scripting language, or transfer protocol I could use from the Pi's side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest [rsync](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync) to copy the files and [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to run the rsync command regularly.
To log into the remote (remote from the Pi's point of view) machine without having to manually type a password each time you need to be able to [log into the remote machine with public/private keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys).

By default rsync doesn't delete files in the destination directory which were deleted in the source directory (just tested it).

Comment: I'll setup public/private keys and rsync - great suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply run rsync on a `cron` job. Run `crontab -e` on Ubuntu and:

```
*/5 * * * *  rsync -a user@raspi:/path/to/files /local/path
```

That will try to sync to two locations every five minutes. That might not be long enough and it'll sync indeterminately (regardless of if something is still being written to - eg being downloaded) so you'll need to take care here.

---

No, that's a lie... I would do one of the following...

- Install a NFS server on the Ubuntu machine and mount it from the Raspi (I actually do do this) and just stream things over the network. You'll need at least 12MB/s (96mbps) for the best quality 1080p content.
- Install a NFS server on the Raspi and download directly to the Raspi. Given the Raspi's slow USB IO and networking, this is less ideal.
- Download the files directly to a dedicated centralised location (eg plugging a harddisk into my router or adding another form of network attached storage) and streaming them to the Pi from there.

They all have slight advantages over a clunky automated copy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The issue with your bottom three solutions is that the two devices are not on the same network. Speed limitations will prevent streaming. I'll likely go with the top solution.